# what am i doing wrong here? calculating standard deviation

Tags: statistics

[image]

> I keep getting 2.02 for the standard deviation but the answer is 0.28?
>   I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I even followed a step-by-step way
>   to calculate it and I'm stilling get it wrong haha :^(

[image]

Comment: You calculated the mean incorrectly: you should have divided by $5$, not by $3$, to get a mean of $3$, not $5$.

Comment: What Brian M. Scott said. You should have noticed something wrong when none of the calculated differences in step #2 were negative.

Comment: WOW YIKES I did not notice that. Thanks!

Comment: If a bunch of numbers are all less than $5$, then their average cannot be $5$. That's definitely something to be aware of. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I corrected it, here it is if anyone is curious haha.